# How to detect when redirect happens in React?

Tags: reactjs, redirect, react-hooks, next.js

There is a redirect and a `data` query para is sent, but unsupprisingly `useEffect` not get triggered, why?

Tried this:

```js
    useEffect(() => {
        console.log('LRAL useff get called')
        if (router.query.data) {
        }
    }, [router.query.data])
```

and this:

```js
    useEffect(() => {
        console.log('LRAL useff get called')
        if (router.query.data) {
        }
    }, [])
```

and this:

```js
    useEffect(() => {
        console.log('LRAL useff get called')
        if (router.query.data) {
        }
    }, [router.query])
```

And also with `react-router-dom` none worked.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using `next/router`, you can try to change your `useEffect` dependancy as

```
useEffect(() => {
        console.log('LRAL useff get called')
        ...
}, [router.pathname])
```

Next.js Router Object: https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next/router#router-object